# How to keep the oAuth 2.0 Client Secret a secret?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, google-oauth

I have to built an API with oAuth 2.0 specs and I have clients that do not use the HTTPS protocol. My question is whether the client secret used to obtain an authorization code can be kept as a secret. If I have to make a request to the Authorization server with the client secret, client id and authorization code as parameter wouldn't it be possible to steal information from this request? Will creating a signature with the authorization code and the client secret help? Even if all the clients are forced to have HTTPS will this be required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC 6749 (OAuth 2.0), [3.1. Authorization Endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1), the 4th paragraph:

> Since requests to the authorization endpoint result in user
> authentication and the transmission of clear-text credentials (in the
> HTTP response), the authorization server **MUST require the use of TLS**
> as described in Section 1.6 when sending requests to the
> authorization endpoint.

Therefore, **client applications must use TLS (https) when they access the authorization endpoint.**

FYI: A client secret is not required at the authorization endpoint if the client type is 'public' and a client secret has not been issued to the client by the OAuth authorization server. Read RFC 6749 carefully.

Comment: But In cases where the client secret has been issued how will the client send the secret securely to get the access token?

Comment: The token endpoint also MUST be accessed using TLS (https), as described in 3.2. Token Endpoint. TLS secures the transmission of a client secret.